# How to assign buffer size dynamically based on incomming UDP packet size?

Tags: java, udp

This is first time I am working on UDP communication and I have no idea does my knowledge inadequate or document I am referring to does not have enough information.

I have a client server application. Server supposed to send an alert message, Client supposed to establish a connection, be alive as long as the app is alive, receive the notification and extract the actual message (to be shown to users). I am able to send the message and receive it by my client.

I have a question:

1. I assigned 2K to my receiver's buffer (`byte[] buf = new byte[2048];`). It might be sufficent for most cases. However, what should I do if backend sends something more than 2048 characters? Doc says the length is dynamic therefore I have no upper bound.

My client code:

```java
public class UDPClient {
    private DatagramSocket udpSocket;
    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int port;
    private Scanner scanner;

    private UDPClient(String destinationAddr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(destinationAddr);
        this.port = port;
        udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(this.port);
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        UDPClient sender = new UDPClient("192.168.1.102", 8888);
        print("-- Running UDP Client at " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + " --");
        sender.listen();
    }

    private void listen() throws IOException {
        String msg;

        String in = scanner.nextLine();
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(in.getBytes(), in.getBytes().length, serverAddress, port);
        this.udpSocket.send(p);

        while (true) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, serverAddress, port);

            // blocks until a packet is received
            udpSocket.receive(packet);
            msg = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

            print("Message from " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ": " + msg);
            parseNotification(msg);
        }
    }

    private static void print(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private void parseNotification(String notification) {
        byte[] actual = notification.getBytes();
        print("Actual length: " + actual.length);

        byte[] response = UDPResponse.hexStringToByteArray(notification);
        Message message = getMessageFromEASNotification(response);
        print("Final message in json:");
        print(message.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no acknowledgements in UDP. If you want information from your client, the client will have to send it. 2048 is 2K, not 2M, and 2M is far too large for a UDP datagram. So in all probability is 2K. The generally accepted practical maximum is 534 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @user207421, my bad. I updated my question to fix 2K issue.

Comment: Your new question is still answered by my old comment.